# Mejora de Consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Requiero de su valiosa ayuda

Tengo dos tablas una de `empleados` y otra de `asistencias`, genere un reporte con las asistencias de las personas fecha Inicio y fecha fin, pero ahora me solicitan que el reporte se con una estructura  como esta, que totalice el total de horas trabjadas por dia y que su resultado este frente a cada empleado

Ej:

| Lunes | Martes | Miercoles | Nom empleado | Horas laboradas | Horas laboradas | Horas laboradas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Esta es la consulta que utilice para el reporte Normal:

```
SELECT 
   DATE(clock_in) AS Work_date, 
   t.badge_id AS badge_id, 
   e.temp_agency, 
   CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name) AS name, 
   t.clock_in AS Star_Time, 
   t.clock_break_in AS Out_lunch, 
   t.clock_break_out AS In_lunch,
   t.clock_out AS End_time,
   ROUND( timestampdiff(minute, (t.clock_in), (t.clock_break_in))/ (60),2) AS before_luch, 
   ROUND( timestampdiff(minute, (t.clock_break_out), (t.clock_out))/(60),2) AS after_lunch,
   ((ROUND( timestampdiff(minute, (t.clock_in), (t.clock_break_in))/ (60),2))+
   (ROUND( timestampdiff(minute, (t.clock_break_out), (t.clock_out))/(60),2))) AS Total
                
FROM employee_time_clock t 
INNER JOIN employee e ON t.badge_id = e.badge_id 
WHERE clock_in BETWEEN '2021-09-26' AND '2021-10-03' 
GROUP BY Work_date ;
```

y este es el resultado:

| Work_date | badge_id | name | temp_agency | Star_Time | Out_lunch | In_lunch | End_time | before_luch | after_lunch | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-05 | EMP1vfvf495 | Alejandra Campos | ACS | 2021-10-05 09:49:43 | 2021-10-05 13:54:55 | 2021-10-05 14:25:20 | 2021-10-05 17:05:34 | 4.08 | 2.67 | 6.75 |
| 2021-10-05 | EMP1vf958 | Alex Andrade | ACS | 2021-10-05 10:56:03 | 2021-10-05 14:35:16 | 2021-10-05 15:09:24 | 2021-10-05 17:24:51 | 3.65 | 2.25 | 5.90 |
| 2021-10-05 | EMvfvf503 | Alfonso Sanchez | SouthBay | 2021-10-05 09:57:05 | 2021-10-05 14:04:00 | 2021-10-05 14:34:04 | 2021-10-05 16:57:22 | 4.10 | 2.38 | 6.48 |
| 2021-10-05 | Evfv116715 | Alicia Diaz | ACS | 2021-10-05 09:52:36 | 2021-10-05 13:02:58 | 2021-10-05 13:33:04 | 2021-10-05 16:30:31 | 3.17 | 2.95 | 6.12 |

de antemano muchas gracias por su colaboracion....

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Realmente no existe error alguno que resolver, tampoco mejora alguna que realizar. Lo que buscas es hacer otra consulta diferente a la que tienes. No es mejorarla, es hacer otra. Esta pregunta debería ser cerrada por que el OP necesita desarrollar la lógica para el nuevo requerimiento que le han hecho.

Comment: No error no hay en la primera que realice solo que no se como estructurar el nuevo requerimiento muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @AndresSanchez, podrías armar una [tabla](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) para ver como sería la salida requerida (puedes utilizar para ello los datos de la query actual).